# Is it possible to insert epoch time in cassandra?

Tags: java, scala, cassandra

schema for table:

```
CREATE TABLE student(
name text,
id int,
class int,
logintime timeuuid,
subject text
PRIMARY KEY ((cust_sub_id, group_id), level, eventtime));
```

when inserting the data in student table:

```
INSERT INTO student(name, id, class, logintime, subject) VALUES ( 'xyz', 10, 12, 242aa080-9e6f-11e5-b62b-903c9927ffc2, 'maths');
```

it is working fine. 
but It is possible to insert epochtime/datetime instead of uuid and automatically save as uuid format in cassandra table?

something like:

```
INSERT INTO student(name, id, class, logintime, subject) VALUES ( 'xyz', 10, 12, 1449663555, 'maths');
```

If not possible then how to convert epochtime to uuid in scala?

Or how to modify the existing uuid increasing by 1 day means [exitingDate + 1.day]??

Answer (score 1):

You can use [timeuuid](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/timeuuid_functions_r.html) data type for that. It looks and tastes like regular UUID, but consists of two parts: time and node-specific random data. It can be used like:

```
INSERT INTO student(name, id, class, logintime, subject) VALUES ( 'xyz', 10, 12, now(), 'maths');
```

Yuo can extract the time portion of TimeUUID by using dateOf() function:

```
SELECT dateOf(logintime) from student where name='xyz';
```

BTW there is also `writetime()` function which can be applied to any (non-PK) column value to get the actual column write timestamp.